# Angularjs + Typescript, How to use $routeParams with IRouteParamsService

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-routing

I am using the $routeParams to pull in properties from the URI and set local vars to them.

When I use typescripts typing to set the type of $routeParams, I can no loger access the $routeParams.

How can I access the properties in the $routeParams?

```
class Controller{
    constructor($routeParams: ng.route.IRouteParamsService, private $location: ng.ILocationService)
        this.propetry1 = this.getProperty1($routeParams.property1);
    }

    property1: string;

    getProperty1(input: string):string{
        return (input || "Not present");
    }
```

}

The ng.route.IRouteParamsService code is:

```
interface IRouteParamsService {
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

This has a error: the property 'property1 does not exist on type of ng.route.IRouteParamsService'

If I change the type of $routeParams to :any then it correctly sets property1.
How can I keep the strict typing of Typescript while still acessing the properties in $routeParams?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Figured it out. You need to declare an Interface that uses IRouteParamsService and specifies the properties you want to use.

```
 interface IRouteParams extends ng.route.IRouteParamsService {
    property1:string;
 }

 class Controller{
    constructor($routeParams: IRouteParams, private $location: ng.ILocationService)
        this.propetry1 = this.getProperty1($routeParams.property1);
    }

    property1: string;

    getProperty1(input: string):string{
        return (input || "Not present");
    }
}
```

Notice the change in the constructor of the controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$routeParams['property1']` instead of `$routeParams.property1`