# AngularJS Typescript IRouteParamsService undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-routing

I´am using angular-route.
Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315893/angularjs-typescript-how-to-use-routeparams-with-irouteparamsservice) I´ve tried to get the URL parameter.

I get the following error:
`angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'zvar' of undefined`
It seems that `$routeParams` is undefined.

My routing config:
`angular.module('app').config(['$routeProvider',
    function routes($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/start.html',
            })
            .when('/calc/:zvar?', {
                templateUrl: 'views/calc.html',
                controller: 'app.controllers.calcCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }
]);`

My URL: `http://localhost:64025/#/calc?zvar=test123`

The access in the constructor:

```
interface IRouteParams extends ng.route.IRouteParamsService {
        zvar: string;
    }
export class calcCtrl implements IController {
        static $inject: string[] = ['$routeParams'];
        constructor(private $routeParams: IRouteParams) {
            this.zvar = $routeParams.zvar;
            console.log("Calc Controller: " + this.zvar);
        }
        zvar: string;
    }
```

Full Typescript code: http://codepen.io/alexmallinger/pen/qNQRGJ

EDIT: Added the line `static $inject: string[] = ['$routeParams'];` to my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inject `$routeParams` service. [$inject property annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation) can be used for this:

```
export class calcCtrl implements IController {
    static $inject:string[] = ['$routeParams'];
    constructor(private $routeParams: IRouteParams) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is controller registered?

Comment: Yes.
I uploaded the full Typescript code here: http://codepen.io/alexmallinger/pen/qNQRGJ

Comment: Try to register controller without `services` array: `angular.module('app.controllers').controller(controller, app.controllers[className]);`

Comment: THANK YOU! I found the problem.
Use `any` instead of `IRouteParams` in `constructor(private $routeParams: any) {`

Comment: `any` - shouldn't be a problem.. also types are not reflected in produced javascript